# Sending images to waffle server in lua from java

Tags: java, image, post, lua

I am trying to send an image from java to a waffle server which is built on aSync - lua.
The following is the code snippet at the server

```
require 'image'
app = require('waffle')
app.get('/', function(req, res)
res.send('Hello World!')
end)
app.post('/', function(req, res)
print(req.form.file)

local img = req.form.file:toImage()
local m = img:mean()
res.send('Image mean: ' .. m)

end)
app.error(500, function(description, req, res)
res.status(500).send(description)
end)
app.listen({host = '0.0.0.0', port=8090})
```

I am able to send an image using a rest Client like Postman
Image sent via post man
[The request contains just a url and form data with the name file and the Same file is uploaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFt2M.jpg)

When i am trying to send the same image using java, i get an error stating

/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/graphicsmagick/Image.lua:352: magick.Image: error reading from blob:  (ExceptionType=0)

The following is the code snippet i am using

```
String url = "http://something:8090";
File f = new File("C:\\Users\\ADRAJ\\Desktop\\Jpg.jpg");
ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(f, "image/jpeg");
HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase post = new HttpPost(url);
post.setEntity(MultipartEntityBuilder.create().addPart("file", cbFile).build());
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(post);
InputStream data2 = response.getEntity().getContent();
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(data2));
String responseLine;
StringBuilder responseBuilder = new StringBuilder();
while ((responseLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
responseBuilder.append(responseLine);
}
```

Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

setLaxmode() on the entity builder solved this